# PHP MYSQL: two while echo from two table to create an ajax live search

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My project involves the creation of an Ajax live search which will display the cities and hotels, taken from two separate tables, based on the text entered in the input field.

The code works regularly if I set a single while, but the cities and hotels are displayed alternately. Instead, I would like the results to be divided; that is, first the hotels, then the cities.

I created the following code:

```
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['term']);
if(isset($term)){
$sql = "select * FROM pt_locations WHERE location LIKE '" . $term . "%' LIMIT 3";


if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $ID_city = $row['ID'];


            $sql2 = "select hotel_title FROM pt_hotels WHERE hotel_code LIKE '" . $ID_city . "%' LIMIT 3";
                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                        echo "<div id='wrap_search'><div id='left_col'><img src='images/hotel.png' alt='icon search hotel'></div>";
                        echo "<div id='right_col'><p>" . substr($row2['hotel_title'], 0, 25) . " ... "."</p></div></div>";


                        }

                    }

                }

            echo "<div id='wrap_search'><div id='left_col'><img src='images/background-world-map.png' alt='icon search city'></div>";
            echo "<div id='right_col'><p>" . $row['location'] . ' - ' . $row['country'] . "</p></div></div>";
        }
        // Close result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "<p>Nessun risultato</p>";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

but returns the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql2' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/vhosts/allrentis.com/car.allrentis.com/definitivo/backend-search.php on line 25
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. You forgot a `;` at the end of line 22 so the next line fails to parse.

Comment: you forgot to place semicolon (;)  after $ID_city = $row['ID']

Comment: you missed the semicolon on the line $ID_city = $row['ID']

Comment: Thank you for the report. Adding (;) the problem of the error is solved, but no result is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the semicolon (`;`) in the end of following line

```
$ID_city = $row['ID'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the report. Adding (;) the problem of the error is solved, but no result is displayed.

Comment: That you need to check what result you are getting from the query, use `var_dump($row2);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a ; after $ID_city = $row['ID']